# Ignorar URL Amigavel para determinadas pastas no .HTACCESS

Tags: php, htaccess, servidor, redes, opencart

Surgiu um grande problema com um cliente que tenho, ele precisa ter duas lojas (usando Open Cart) no mesmo dominio, só que ambas são de produtos, layout e plug-ins diferentes (por isso não posso fazer duas lojas, como o Open Cart possibilita).
As URLs ficariam assim

> www.loja.com.br
>
> www.loja.com.br/outra

Preciso desabilitar essa pasta (/outra/) no .HTACCESS da loja que está na raiz, pois esta pasta tem suas proprias configurações e exibições de erros, entretanto está herdando tudo do .HTACCESS da loja raiz.

Segue o .HTACCESS da loja raiz (sem os comentários)

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
Options -Indexes

<FilesMatch "\.(tpl|ini|log)">
 Order deny,allow
 Deny from all
</FilesMatch>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap [L]
RewriteRule ^googlebase.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_base [L]
RewriteRule ^download/(.*) /index.php?route=error/not_found [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Poderia postar o conteúdo do `.htaccess` da loja raiz? Creio que é só fazer a condição do ReWrite Engine não capturar nada com `/outra`, mas poste aí para termos uma idéia.

Comment: opa, é o padrão do Open Cart 1.5.x
atualizei a postagem

Comment: Tente adicionar a seguinte linha (antes da última):

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|outra)